# Repainting panel in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, panel, repaint

I am working on task scheduling software and its going great so far, except one thing - my panels are not getting repainted sometimes.I am working on calendar visual interface now, and i represent different days with panels, and  events are represented by other panels put in the 'day' panel. I have a list of appointntments :

```
 ArrayList<JPanel> appPanelList = new ArrayList<JPanel>();
```

Now say we got a button to add a panel to this list and also to 'panel_days' panel:

```
 btnAddApp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            appPanelList.add(new JPanel());             
            appPanelList.get(0).setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
            appPanelList.get(0).setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, null, null));
            panel_days.add(appPanelList.get(0), "flowx,cell 0 1,growx,growy");
            panel_days.repaint();

        }
    });
```

and other button deletes this appointment:

```
btnDeleteApp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panel_days.remove(appPanelList.get(0));
                panel_days.repaint();
            }
        });
```

Now when i click 'btnAddApp' it adds appointment panel to another panel (panel_days) But i can't see it untill I resize window or do other action. As soon as start resizing window, appointment panel appears. And this only happens the first time i add appointment. If i click 'btnDeleteApp' button it deletes appointments and repaints screen, and then if i I try to add appoinment again, it also works now and panels get repainted instantly, It only fails to repaint the first time 'appPanelList.get(0)' is created. Why is this happening?

Comment: Call `revalidate` before `repaint` when you've finished updating (adding/removing components from the) UI

Comment: thanks, love one line fixes!!!

Comment: *"I have a list of appointntments :"*  Use a `JList` for that!